# PostScript rosetta with rotated labels typeset with multido

Tags: pstricks

I aim to set up a rosetta vignette looking like the flower part of this image, although I want the labels slanted, or rotated:

[image: mathematics competencies]

I imagine this can be achieved with node center in polar coordinates, calculating label slant from angular coordinate. Hence, I am looking to run some PSTRICKS macro (involving [`\multido`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/generic/multido/multido.pdf)).

I have achieved to put a single label using MWE

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
  \rput{!112.5 180 sub}(2;112.5){Tankegang}
  \rput{!157.5 180 sub}(2;157.5){Problembehandling}
  \rput{!202.5 180 sub}(2;202.5){Modellering}    
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

providing

[image: ![enter image description here]
However, I imagine to deploy `\multido` in a way similar to

```
\multido{\mbenAngle=112.5+45}{3}{%
  \rput{!\mbenAngle 180 sub}%
       (2;\mbenAngle)%
       {[(Tankegang) (Problembehandling) (Modellering)]\multidocount}%
 }
```

The **failing** intention of the `...]\multidocount` 
is to index a PS array of strings.

But my definition and or my referencing of the PostScript array of strings does not work -- I tried, too, to enclose in square brackets: `...][\multidocount]`

I would be grateful for suggestions as to how I could

1. declare an 3-element array of strings (in the full LaTEX file, 
   there will be 8 labels, in accordance with the image above, 
   but 3 in accordance with MWE),
2. access each element in turn, as `\multido` iterates
3. *(and possibly add a reference point for later annotations 
   at the tip of each lobe or petal, again accessible 
   through some data structure, possibly an array of polar coordinates)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\Names
\readarray{Names}{Tankegang&Problembehandling&Modellering}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\multido{\iA=1+1,\rA=112.5+60.0}{3}{%
  \rput{!\rA\space 180 sub}(2;\rA){\Names(\iA)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your suggestion using [arrayjobx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/arrayjobx/arrayjob.pdf) will work fine in a single-file implementation. Making the preamble more lightweight by placing the statements `\newarray\Names
\readarray{Names}{Tankegang&Problembehandling&Modellering}` within document (immediately preceeding `\multido`. That seems compilable, so I accept.