# Calculated label rotation in postscript

Tags: pstricks, labels, loops, postscript, readarray

Elaborating on a solution obtained from the accepted answer of [my earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376764/69027), I would like to rotate upside-down labels on the righthand side of the rosetta using modulus.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\newarray\Names
\readarray{Names}{Tankegang&Problembehandling&Modellering&Ræsonnement&Hjælpemiddel&Kommunikation&Symbol- og formalisme&Repræsentation}
\multido{\iA=1+1,\rA=112+45}{8}{%
  \rput{!\rA\space 180 sub}(2;\rA){\Names(\iA)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Output of MWE]

What I mean is that I want to calculate label rotation angles **modulo 180**, but contrary to my expectation, `\rput{!\rA\space 180 sub 180 mod}(...` produces multiple copies of the terse error message:

```
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript
9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I compile on a Win10 PC using TexMaker 4.5, calling XeLaTeX.

I read the following discussions, but do not seem to get to a solution:

- [No visible images in PDF: MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219803/69027) and the questions  referenced there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[dvipsnames,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\Names

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-3.75,-3.75)(4.25,3.75)
    \readarray{Names}{%
        Tankegang&Problembehandling&Modellering&%
        Ræsonnement&Hjælpemiddel&Kommunikation&%
        Symbol-og formalisme&Repræsentation}
    \multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=112+45}{8}{%
        \ifnum\iB<270 
          \rput[r]{!\iB\space 180 add}(1;\iB){\Names(\iA)}%
        \else
          \rput[l]{\iB}(1;\iB){\Names(\iA)}%
        \fi}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `!\rA\space cvi 180 sub 180 mod`

Comment: Ah, failing to convert to integer (cvi) was what missed! And, in all probablilty, what triggered the mentioned error message.

Comment: Instead of `\rA` you can also use `\iB` then you do not need the conversion into an integer. In your first example you startet with a real angle value. However, I have no idea about your error message because I do not have any problem.

Comment: Correct, I edited MWE in an attemt to work around having `mod` provoking the mentioned error.  Both arguments to `mod` must be integers.

Comment: Actually, `!\iB\space 90 add 180 mod 90 sub` does the trick of correctly rotating the labels as wished.

Comment: See my edited answer ...

Comment: Elegant solution avoiding `mod` altogether